# Splitting image result into Pages

Tags: php, html, paging

I have this code that shows all the images inside 'images' directory but it is very annoying because all the images are showing on a single page :/

how could i split those images on multiple pages ?

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<?php 
$files = glob("images/*.*"); 
echo '<div id="design">';

for ($i=0; $i<count($files); $i++) { 
    $num = $files[$i];
        if ($i%3==0){echo '<div class="Row">';}
        echo '<img class="img" width="250px" height="250px" src="'.$num.'" alt="random image" />'; 
        if ($i%3==0){echo '</div>';}
    }

echo '</div>';  
?>
```

Comment: look into pagination: http://phpeasystep.com/phptu/29.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try replacnig this line with something more rubust. This will return all files (image or anything else) unless you are sure that only image files are in the folder:

```
$files = glob("images/*.*");
```

The `$files` will result in an array with paths to the images, you can easily use this feature to display only the number of images you want in a page.

like this:

```
<?php     

$imagesPerPage = 10;

if(!isset($_GET["start"]))
{
    $start = 0;
}
else
{
    $start = $_GET["start"];
}

$files = glob("images/*.*");     

for($i = $start; $i < $start + $imagesPerPage; $i++)
{
   if(isset($files[$i]))
   {
       echo "<img src=\"".$files[$i]."\" width=\"100\" height=\"100\" />\r\n";
   }
}

$start = $start + $imagesPerPage;       

echo "<br />\r\n";
echo "<a href=\"index.php?start={$start}\">NEXT</a>";
?>
```

You can follow the same rules and make a pervious link as well!

Please note, stopping (disabling) NEXT or Pervious links is up to yourself!

Answer (score 2):

Pagination! Here's a starting point:

```
// glob list of images
$files = glob('images/*');

// for consistency, you'll have to sort the resulting array...
natcasesort($files);

// get a page number from a query string e.g: ?page=1
$page = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);

// filter_input returns null if there is no page value in the qs,
// so let's check that and add a default value if we need to
$page = $page ?: 1;

// slice the array! get a subset of the files array based on
// an offset (page number) and length (results per page)
$resultsPerPage = 5;
$slice = array_slice($files, (($page - 1) * $resultsPerPage), $resultsPerPage);
```

You can now display your subset of results as normal. Of course you'll have to supply a series of links for each page... That's straightforward: get the length of your `$files` array, and use your `$resultsPerPage` value to figure out how many pages you need to display.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Quick note: The ternary shortcut `$page = $page ?: 1;` is a PHP >= 5.3 feature; if you are using <= 5.2 then replace this with `if (null === $page) $page = 1;` or whatever.

Comment: You're welcome :) It's pretty neat. Lots and lots of great filtering options. Helps cut out some of the validation boilerplate!